# Creating gridlayout not working in android

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

In my android app, I want to make a gridlayout of a 5x5 grid. No spacing in between any rows/columns. The grid should match the parent width/height with a 10dp margins. Also all the cells should have equal width and height (i.e. all widths the same, and all heights the same even if width not equals height).

This is what I have so far but nothing shows

```
public class ColorGrid {

    private Context context;
    private RelativeLayout container = null;
    private GridLayout gridlayout = null;

    public ColorGrid(RelativeLayout container) {
        this.context = container.getContext();
        this.container = container;
        this.gridlayout = createGrid();


        for(int i=0; i<25; i+=1) {
            addCell();
        }

        container.addView(gridlayout);
    }

    private GridLayout createGrid() {
        GridLayout gridview = new GridLayout(context);

        gridview.setColumnCount(5);
        gridview.setRowCount(5);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gridview.setLayoutParams(params);

        return gridview;
    }

    private void addCell() {
        View cell = new View(context);
        cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, 1.0f);
        cell.setLayoutParams(params);

        gridlayout.addView(cell);
    }

    public void dismiss() {
        if (container != null && gridlayout != null) {
            container.removeView(gridlayout);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks